# Как перезаписать N битов в определенной позиции без перезаписи остальных в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

У меня появилась проблема при перезаписи уже установленных битов на определенных позициях. Не могу найти решение, как перезаписывать N битов, которые уже были установлены на 1.

Для наглядности проблемы, я написал примерную реализацию того, что я делаю у себя.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    quint32 val = 0;

    val |= ((0 & 0x03) << 0x1E);
    qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, 32, 2, QChar('0'));
    // I get      : 00000000000000000000000000000000
    // Should get : 00000000000000000000000000000000

    val |= ((1 & 0x03) << 0x1E);
    qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, 32, 2, QChar('0'));
    // I get      : 01000000000000000000000000000000
    // Should get : 01000000000000000000000000000000

    val |= ((2 & 0x03) << 0x1E);
    qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, 32, 2, QChar('0'));
    // I get      : 11000000000000000000000000000000
    // Should get : 10000000000000000000000000000000

    val |= ((3 & 0x03) << 0x1E);
    qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, 32, 2, QChar('0'));
    // I get      : 11000000000000000000000000000000
    // Should get : 11000000000000000000000000000000

    val |= ((2 & 0x03) << 0x1E);
    qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, 32, 2, QChar('0'));
    // I get      : 11000000000000000000000000000000
    // Should get : 10000000000000000000000000000000

    val |= ((1 & 0x03) << 0x1E);
    qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, 32, 2, QChar('0'));
    // I get      : 11000000000000000000000000000000
    // Should get : 01000000000000000000000000000000

    val |= ((0 & 0x03) << 0x1E);
    qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, 32, 2, QChar('0'));
    // I get      : 11000000000000000000000000000000
    // Should get : 00000000000000000000000000000000

}
```

Меня интересует именно реализация кода таким образом, чтобы при установки значений для определенных битов, не производилось затрагивание состояние битов не относящихся к установке значений. Я заметил, что если определенный бит был выставлен на значение 1 - то при перезаписи, я не могу установить его в 0.

Например, если в `quint32`, с `0` бита по `7`, я хочу установить максимальное значение - `127`, то при уменьшение этого значения, например на `8`, я всеравно получаю `127`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Не могу найти решение, как перезаписывать N битов, которые уже были установлены на 1.

Сначала надо обнулить биты AND'ом, а потом присваивать им значение OR'ом:

```
val = (val & ~(0x03 << 30)) | (high_bits << 30)
           /*  0x3fffffff */
```

Для произвольной группы битов это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
int bit_sz = 0x02;      //< размер битового поля
int bit_offset = 0x30;  //< смещение битового поля от младший битов
int bit_mask = ~(~0 << bit_sz) << bit_offset; //< маска битового поля, 0xc0000000

val = (val & ~bit_mask) | new_bit_val << bit_offset
```